# Word Map for Emotions

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a resource similar to WordNet. However, I want to be able to look up the positive/negative connotation of a word. For example:

```
bribe - negative
offer - positive
```

I'm curious as to whether anyone has run across any tool like this in AI/NLP research, or even in linguistics.

**UPDATE:**
For the curious, the accepted answer below put me on the right track towards what I needed. Wikipedia listed several different resources. The two I would recommend (because of ease of use/free use for a small number of API calls) are [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/) and [Lymbix](http://www.lymbix.com/). I decided to go with AlchemyAPI, since people affiliated with academic institutions (like myself) and non-profits can get even more API calls per day if they just email the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start looking up topics on 'sentiment analysis':  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I'll post what I found above.

Answer (score 1):

The are some vocabulary compilations regarding affect, aka dictionaries of affect, such as the Affective Norms of English Words (ANEW) or the Dictionary of Affect in Language (DAL). They provide a dimensional representation of affect (valence, activation and control) that may be of use in a sentiment analysis scenario (detection of positive/negative connotation). In this sense, [EmoLib](http://dtminredis.housing.salle.url.edu:8080/EmoLib/) works with the former, by default, but may be easily extended with a more specific lexicon to tackle particular needs (for example, EmoLib provides an additional neutral label that is more appropriate than the positive/negative tag set alone in a Text-To-Speech synthesis setting).

Answer (score 0):

There is also [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/), which gives you positive, negative and objective scores for each WordNet synset.

However, you should be aware that the positive and negative connotation of a term often depends on the context in which it is used. A great introduction to this topic is the book [*Opinion mining and sentiment analysis* by Bo Pang and Lillian Lee](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/opinion-mining-sentiment-analysis-survey.html), which is available online for free.